# convert dask series into dask dataframe

Tags: python-3.5, dask

I would like to know how to convert a `dask.dataframe.core.Series` to a dask dataframe.

I have:

`type(card_id_pur_freq)`

output:

`dask.dataframe.core.Series`

I tried:

`card_id_pur_freq = dd.DataFrame(card_id_pur_freq)`

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-bd6cdab52455> in <module>
----> 1 card_id_pur_freq = dd.DataFrame(card_id_pur_freq)

TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'meta', and 'divisions'
```

I would like to know how to convert a dask series into a dataframe.

Please let me know. @MRocklin

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `.to_frame()` method

```
df = s.to_frame()
```